# Trigger Duplicate CSV

Tags: salesforce, apex-code, force.com

am trying to upload a CSV file / insert a bulk of records using the import wizard. In short I would like to keep the latest record, in case if duplicates are found. Duplicates record are a combination of First name, Last name and title

For example if my CSV file looks like the following:

James,Wistler,34,New York,Married
James,Wistler,34,London,Married
....
....

James,Wistler,34,New York,Divorced

This should only keep in my org: **James,Wistler,34,New York,Divorced**

I have been trying to write a trigger before an update / insert but so far no success Here is my trigger code: (The code is not yet finished (only filering with Firstname), I am having a problem deleting found duplicate in my CSV ) Any hints. Thanks for reading!

```
trigger CheckDuplicateInsert on Customer__c(before insert,before update){

Map <String, Customer__c> customerFirstName = new Map<String,Customer__c>();
list <Customer__c> CustomerList = Trigger.new;

for (Customer__c newCustomer : CustomerList)
{
    if ((newCustomer.First_Name__c != null) && System.Trigger.isInsert )
    {
        if (customerFirstName.containsKey(newCustomer.First_Name__c) )
        //remove the duplicate from the map
        customerFirstName.remove(newCustomer.First_Name__c);
        //end of the if clause
    // add this stage we dont have any duplicate, so lets add a new customer
    customerFirstName.put(newCustomer.First_Name__c , newCustomer);
    }  
    else if ((System.Trigger.oldMap.get(newCustomer.id)!= null)&&newCustomer.First_Name__c !=System.Trigger.oldMap.get(newCustomer.id).First_Name__c )
    {//field is being updated, lets mark it with UPDATED for tracking
    newCustomer.First_Name__c=newCustomer.First_Name__c+'UPDATED';
    customerFirstName.put(newCustomer.First_Name__c , newCustomer);
    }

 }


for (Customer__c customer : [SELECT First_Name__c FROM Customer__c WHERE First_Name__c IN  :customerFirstName.KeySet()])
{
    if (customer.First_Name__c!=null)
    {
        Customer__c newCustomer=customerFirstName.get(customer.First_Name__c);
        newCustomer.First_Name__c=Customer.First_Name__c+'EXIST_DB';
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Purely non-SF solution would be to sort them & deduplicate in Excel for example ;)

---

Good news - you don't need a trigger. Bad news - you might have to ditch the import wizard and start using Data Loader. The solution is pretty long and looks scary but once you get the hang of it it should start to make more sense and be easier to maintain in future than writing code.

You can download the Data Loader in setup area of your Production org and here's some [basic info about the tool](http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Data_Loader).

Anyway.

1. I'd make a new text field on your Contact, call it "unique key" or something and mark it as External Id. If you have never used ext. ids - Jeff Douglas has [a good post about them](http://blog.jeffdouglas.com/2010/05/07/using-exernal-id-fields-in-salesforce/).
2. You might have to populate the field on your existing data before proceeding. Easiest would be to export all Contacts where it's blank (from a report for example), fill it in with some Excel formulas and import back.
3. If you want, you can even write a workflow rule to handle the generation of the unique key. This might help you when Mrs. Jane Doe gets married and becomes Jane Bloggs and also will make previous point easier (you'd just import Contacts without changes, just "touching" them and the workflow will fire). Something like

   - condition: `ISBLANK(Unique_key__c) || ISCHANGED(FirstName) || ISCHANGED(LastName) || ISCHANGED(Title)`
   - new value: `Title + FirstName + ' ' + LastName`
4. Almost there. Fire Data Loader and prepare an upsert job (because we want to insert some records and when duplicate is found - update them instead).
5. My only concern is what happens when what's effectively same row will appear more than once in 1 "batch" of records sent to SF like in your example. Upsert will not know which value is valid (it's like setting `x = 7;` and `x = 5;` in same save to DB) and will decide to fail these rows. So you might have to tweak the amount of records in a batch in Data Loader's settings.

Comment: Thanks Eyescream for the break through steps. But as you might have red it elsewhere (sorry about this, I thought they were two different places) I will need to stick with writing a trigger :/